# What are some good resources for learning about Web Services with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web

I'm completely new in web service. I want to study about it and the use it in my web site?

any practical tutorial please?

Comment: @odiseh: a quick internet search will answer your question.

Comment: @Mitch: of course there's lots of resources there, but what I want to study is one that some one has studied it before and has marked it a good starting point.

Comment: Then I would recommend rewording your question to get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I edited your title to better reflect the info you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several of the other answers have suggested that you learn obsolete or legacy technologies. There is no reason to do that.

All new web service development on the .NET platform should be done using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). WCF replaces both the ASMX and WSE technologies, and then greatly expands their functionality.

The [WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) is the place to start. Among other things, it includes [Learning WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936243.aspx), a set of tutorials on WCF.

Answer (score 2):

If its WCF Services then check out the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

or maybe a book! Programming WCF Services, Second Edition (OReilly)

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521325

EDIT: Beginners should focus on WCF as advised and not old school .asmx services.

Comment: -1: Please do not suggest that a beginner start off in the past. All new web service development should be done using WCF.

Comment: The question referred web services so thats why I put resources for both WCF and old-style web services. WCF has wider scope.

Comment: it's possible I'm over-sensitive to this, but I frequently deal with people who decide to _start_ with WSE because of something they read online. Your answer is one of those that could be misunderstood, since you place ASMX and WSE on the same level as WCF.

Comment: @John Saunders: no problem I agree with you regarding WCF. I think it is also always good to keep track of older technologies - they can often get you out of a hole!!

Comment: it's ok for you and I - but it will only confuse a beginner. If you update your answer to omit the old stuff, I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Search for terms like WCF, WSDL, SOAP. I Would recommend buying a book!

Comment: -1: and I wish I could downvote more. Do **not** suggest a beginner start by learning obsolete technologies like ASMX and WSE.

Comment: and I wish the whole world is using WCF. As long that is not the case you will have to know some of the older technologies. There is nothing bad in learning some history.

Comment: dead wrong. Teach him modern techniques, and if he ever needs history, he can get it then. There's no reason to confuse the issue until then.

Comment: @John: I was just trying to say that there is more then WCF only out there. Ofcourse he should start with WCF.

Comment: if you update your answer to omit "ASMX" and "WSE", then I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I found useful: [a very in-depth series of articles at 4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134052/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100803-1.aspx). Although it's quite old now it will give you a good grounding.

Edit: After my wrist-slap from John, perhaps you should skip my first link and [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx).

Comment: -1: why would you want to suggest that a beginner learn anything about WSE or ASMX web services?

Comment: Fair point—although I would say that a lot of companies we deal with where I work still use ASMX services, so it might be useful to at least know something about them. This is just a tutorial that I found useful when I was originally learning.

Comment: B: he can always go back and learn "stone knives and bearskins" later. He will at least do so having known how a web service framework _should_ be constructed. Downvote removed due to your edit.